# How set echarts treemap series color forcely

Tags: javascript, colors, series, treemap, echarts

Just for all who are insearch of it! I've spend almost 2 hours to make it working!
How set color for series in echarts treemap forcely

`levels:{ color:["#eba080","#2d2554","#40522a","#9f1f1f","#a48679","#542261"], colorMappingBy: 'value', }`
WARNING! Insert just for Levels, NOT for itemStyles !

I hope somebody'll save some time due to my post )

Full example:

```
echarts.init($('.treemap')[0]).setOption({
        series: [{type: 'treemap', breadcrumb: {show: false, top: '92%'}, top: 30,
        levels: [{
            color:["#eba080","#2d2554","#40522a","#9f1f1f","#a48679","#542261"], colorMappingBy: 'value' }
            itemStyle: {borderColor: '#222', borderWidth: 0, gapWidth: 1},
            upperLabel: {show: false}
        }],
        data: data
});
```

Comment: please add [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.